# How to calculate efficiency of an electrical circuit that can mimick neural network

Tags: integrated-circuit, efficiency

Looking at the progress of the gpt models, i started thinking how they would be deployed to edge devices, and if that is the best way: currently using API calls.

I then started looking into mimicking a simple neural network using analog circuit, qualitatively using analog circuit to define weights that are usually training output for these networks.

Models like chatgpt or further iterations would not be simple neural networks but transformer models that in itself would be different in implementing as electrical circuits. However since the the architecture on which even embedded circuits deploy ai models using tools like tiny-ml or tf-lite, weren't designed to run neural networks hence it makes sense to think again how to better design integrated chip designs that are more efficient at this.

My question is how does one go about predicting, by calculations, how much better would such a custom analog circuit be instead of computingg the mathematical equations equivalent to these circuits.

Comment: Maybe ask chatgpt but, don't post the answer back here because chatgpt responses are banned as far as I know on this site. What does the word "efficiency" mean to you?

Answer (score 1):

I think the first step would be to design and build a single analog artificial neuron, with all its required features, such as the ability to propagate weights, etc. (AI is not my field, but I get the basic ideas.)

Then: Try to determine the best speed achievable for a whole network, and its requirements in terms of electrical power and physical space.

FWIW, ChatGPT has [175 billion neurons](https://3quarksdaily.com/3quarksdaily/2023/02/chatgpt-is-a-miracle-of-rare-device-heres-how-im-thinking-about-it.html#:%7E:text=It%20is%20an%20artificial%20neural,consists%20175%20billion%20artificial%20neurons.) so start saving your money for a nuclear power plant.